# Looping through a generic list : If string contains a number, add to a list and sort it

Tags: vb.net, list

I would like to take a generic list and pull out the strings that contain numbers and add it to a new list. I would also like to sort it.

```
Sub list()
     Dim tests New List(Of String)
     test.Add("1 car")
     test.Add("8 boat")
     test.ForEach(.............)
End Sub
```

Comment: `C#` is not `VB.NET`, and if your question does not ask about `c#` the tag does not apply. The same applies to the `query` tag - `query` refers to using SQL to *query* a database, and there's nothing about that in your question either. Tags are designed to categorize questions so that they can be used in a search or get the attention of people who are interested in those topics. Please limit tags to those that actually apply to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Simple. Either one is fine. I will reword it. Thanks

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Adding `C#` to a question asking about VB.NET does not make it a C# question. As I said, the tags are here for a reason.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “contain numbers”? Just at the beginning? Followed by whitespace? Or does the presence of at least one digit anywhere in a string satisfy your criterion?

Comment: @Ken OP clearly said that “either one is fine” – so the question is *not* “about VB”. And since the languages are only distinguishable by syntax you’ll find quite a lot of questions on SO which (legitimately!) have both tags.

Comment: @Konrad: Agreed, but the original question's only reference to C# was in the tags (which also included `query`). The non-compiling pseudo code snippet posted was clearly not C# (but might have been an attempt at VB.NET), and the "either/or" was added in an edit. Tags should not be grabbed at random (as query was) if the tag system is to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done VB.NET in a while, and am not familiar with the syntax for how they declare lists, but in C# you can do it this way. Probably not efficient and you can convert to get an idea:

```
var a = new List<string> { "2 good morning", "1 hello", "Nope" };
var b = new List<string>();
            int x;
            foreach (string s in a)
            {
                string[] parts = s.Split(' ');
                foreach (string part in parts)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(part, out x))
                    {
                        b.Add(s); // Adding the Entire word here
                    }
                }
            }
            b.Sort();

            b.ForEach(ele => Console.WriteLine(ele));

            Console.Read();

Will Produce:
1 hello
2 good morning
```

Answer (score 0):

With the presumption that the possible number is the first character as per your example:

```
 Dim listOne As New List(Of String)({"1cat", "2dog", "monkey", "1mouse", "blah"})

 Dim listTwo = listOne.Where(Function(x) IsNumeric(x.Substring(0, 1))).ToList

 listTwo.Sort()
```